# Does changing app display name changes its URL on the store?

Tags: android, ios

I want change display name of the app (the one which is displayed below the app icon on user's device). I do not intend to change the app's name or its bundle identifier.
I know how to do it, but want to know if this will also affect the URL of my app on the app store?
Reason I ask this is that I already have published QR codes directing to my app on the app store. If changing the app's display name in the next update is also going to change these URLs, then I will need to publish new QR codes.

Comment: if you have to change the app package name regarding the next app update you updates?

Comment: No it doesn't change the URL.

Comment: it changes only if you change the package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't  affect the URL of your app on the app store. The URL will change only if you change the app package but in this case you have to publish the new version of the app as a new app.

> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name, this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

Source: [Things That Cannot Change](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)